# Passport js multiple strategy authentication gives Bad Request

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am designing some API endpoints that i want to be be accessible to authenticated users.
I chose passport for this task and i also chose two authentication strategies: Bearer and local.
The reason behind that is admin users will use a username and password while mobile applications will provide an access_token.

The problem that I am facing is that when I add two authentication strategy to a route i get a Bad Request error 400.

I have used this as an example [passport.js with multiple authentication providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745296/passport-js-with-multiple-authentication-providers)

below is a sample code:

```
var express = require('express')
, passport = require('passport')
, util = require('util')
, http = require('http')
, BearerStrategy = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy
, LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


var users = [
{id: 1, username: 'bob', password: 'secret', email: 'bob@example.com', token: '123'}
, {id: 2, username: 'joe', password: 'birthday', email: 'joe@example.com', token: '456'}];

function findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password, fn) {
for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (user.username === username && user.password === password) {
        return fn(null, user);
    }
}
return fn(null, null);
}

function findByToken(token, fn) {
for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (user.token === token) {
        return fn(null, user);
    }
}
return fn(null, null);
}

function findById(id, fn) {
for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (user.id === id) {
        return fn(null, user);
    }
}
return fn(null, null);
}


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function (username, password, done) {
    findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password, done);
}
));

passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
function (token, done) {
    findByToken(token, done);
}
));

var app = express();


app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
   done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    findById(id, done);
});


app.route('/')
    .get(passport.authenticate(['bearer', 'local']),
    function (req, res) {
        res.json({username: req.user.username, email: req.user.email});
    });

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(3000, function onListen(err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
  console.log('app started on port 3000');
});
```

the follwoing are the versions of the modules i am using

```
 "dependencies": {
"express": "^4.12.2",
"passport": "^0.2.1",
"passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0"
 }
```

what could be causing such an issue and how to fix it.

Regards.