# Passport Authentication - Any?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, oauth, passport.js

I am writing a nodejs application with passport.js-based authentication. It lets users message other users, where only authenticated users are allowed to retriever messages either sent by them or with them as the receiver. I am planning to implement multiple identity providers, such as facebook, google, and maybe local authentication as well.

The user schema i set up using mongoose looks like sort of like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  googleId: String,
  facebookId: String,

  email: { type: String, required: true },
}, {
  strict: false
})

module.exports = mongoose.Model('User', userSchema)
```

Now the approach I had in mind was this:

- A user is presented a sign in page
- On this page they are presented a choice of identity providers
- They get redirected to authorization page, granting access to the requested scopes, getting redirected to my specified callback URL
- There is either already a user with the according ID or a new one is created.

Now when they try to receive the message, I want to authenticate them again in order to grant authorization to obtain the message. How they authenticate really does not matter, as long as it is any of the strategies I configured; there is however no such thing as `app.get('/messages', passport.authenticate('any'), done)`, so how would I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to pass the strategies you want as an array into `passport.authenticate([Strategies])`. The link below shows that nicely.

[passport.js with multiple authentication providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745296/passport-js-with-multiple-authentication-providers)

Another example from the author of passport:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http/blob/master/examples/multi/app.js