# Google sign-in and passport.js - how to handle calls from Android and iOS using the same route?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, google-signin

I am using passport.js to authenticate mobile users from Android and iOS app.

```
var GoogleTokenStrategy = require('passport-google-id-token');
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(app) {
     app.use(passport.initialize());
     app.use(passport.session());

     passport.use(new GoogleTokenStrategy({
        clientID: "013323487228-563u02i6dk3vj3ic5q4l9g5r79vhqc4b.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     }, function(parsedToken, googleId, done) {
        // logic for finding user in db
     }
     ));

    app.post('/auth/google',
        passport.authenticate('google-id-token'),
        function (req, res) {
        res.send(req.user? 200 : 401);
        }
    );
}
```

However, client IDs for Android and iOS app are different. How can I handle this? Should I make different endpoints for both cases? Two different strategies? Or even two different routes files for each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this with OAuth strategies, but you can have multiple instances of same strategy by [naming them](http://passportjs.org/docs/authorize), and you can use multiple strategies [in single route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20747016/3349511). So, maybe you could use these and use two strategies:

```
var loginHandler = function(parsedToken, googleId, done) {
    // logic for finding user in db
};

passport.use('android', new GoogleTokenStrategy({
        clientID: "android-token"
    }, loginHandler));

passport.use('ios', new GoogleTokenStrategy({
        clientID: "iphone-token"
    }, loginHandler));
```

Then use both in `authenticate` call:

```
app.post('/auth/google', 
         passport.authenticate(['android', 'ios']), 
         function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.user ? 200 : 401);
});
```

or, if listing multiple strategies won't work, then use route params and [custom callback](http://passportjs.org/docs#custom-callback):

```
app.post('/auth/google/:platform(android|ios)', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate(req.params.platform, function(err, user, info) {
        // ...
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass another parameter in your POST request (`platform: android` or `platform: ios`) and act on that variable on the server side. No need for a different route.